# 404 error and "to many redirects" with traefik and nextcloud

Tags: docker-compose, traefik

Im using Traefik for reverse proxy some services. But something isn't working as expected. I think that it might be a port conflict. When using ports example `192.168.1.10:8080` I'm redirected to Traefik dashboard. But when visiting `192.168.1.10`, I would like to end up at Nextcloud service, but instead I get a 404 error.

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
    version: "3.6"
    services:

    ### TRAEFIK REVERSE PROXY WITH LETTS ECRYPT FOR DOCKER MEDIA SERVER ###
      traefik:
        hostname: traefik
        image: traefik:latest
        container_name: traefik
        restart: always
        domainname: ${DOMAINNAME}
        networks:
          - default
          - traefik_proxy
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
    #      - "8080:8080"
        environment:
          - CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=${CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL}
          - CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=${CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY}
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.backend=traefik"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:traefik.${DOMAINNAME}"  
          - "traefik.port=80"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
        volumes:
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
          - ${USERDIR}/docker/traefik:/etc/traefik
          - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared

    ### NextCloud – Your Own Cloud Storage ### with redis https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/issues/140
      nextcloud:
        container_name: nextcloud
        depends_on:
          - traefik
          - mariadb
          - redis
        restart: always
        image: linuxserver/nextcloud
        volumes:
          - ${USERDIR}/docker/nextcloud:/config
          - ${USERDIR}/shared_data:/data # Path to data you want to share/sync
          - ${USERDIR}/docker/shared:/shared
        ports:
           - "9059:443"
        environment:
          - PUID=${PUID}
          - PGID=${PGID}
        networks:
          - traefik_proxy
          - default
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.backend=nextcloud"
          - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:nextcloud.${DOMAINNAME}"
          - "traefik.port=80"
          - "traefik.protocol=https"
          - "traefik.docker.network=traefik_proxy"
```

This is my Traefik.toml file:

```
    #debug = true
    logLevel = "DEBUG" #DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, PANIC
    InsecureSkipVerify = true
    defaultEntryPoints = ["https", "http"]

    # WEB interface of Traefik - it will show web page with overview of frontend and backend configurations
    [web]
    address = ":8080"
      [web.auth.basic]
      usersFile = "/shared/.htpasswd"

    # Force HTTPS
    [entryPoints]
      [entryPoints.http]
      address = ":80"
        [entryPoints.http.redirect]
        entryPoint = "https"
      [entryPoints.https]
      address = ":443"
        [entryPoints.https.tls]
```

The expected result is hitting nextcloud when visiting `192.168.1.10`.

Answer (score 2):

Your label under nextcloud tells traefik to route traffic matching the frontend rule to port 80 on this service

```
- "traefik.port=80"
```

while your nextcloud service only expose port 443. Change the label to use port 443 instead.

And if you are expecting to hit nextcloud when visiting 192.168.1.10, your frontend rule should be

```
- "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:${DOMAINNAME}"
```

Finally when testing on localhost, it's better to test with curl to avoid other troubles

`curl -H Host:whoami0.traefik http://localhost`

Comment: Thanks! I have made the changes, but I'm still receiving `Connection not secure` and 404 when clicking past the safari/chrome warning. In the traefik log `traefik | 2018-11-22T17:36:38.721997945Z time="2018-11-22T17:36:38Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 192.168.1.108:49637: remote error: tls: unknown certificate authority"
traefik | 2018-11-22T17:37:19.532029621Z time="2018-11-22T17:37:19Z" level=debug msg="Serving default cert for request: \"192.168.1.10\""`

Comment: I get my to my nextcloud container, but denied `Access through untrusted domain`

Comment: that's ok. so you have forced https between browser and traefik but you haven't provided any ssl certificate, need to add that https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/acme/

Comment: I might have gotten things to work! The problem seems that I cannot connect with IP, but adding hostnames in etc/hosts everything seems to work